# Can I generate Azure AD Client Credentials Secrets using an API?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I want to use my Azure AD App Registration to create multiple Client Secrets. I am stuck on two questions and haven't been able to find any documentation around these:

1. Is there an API (Graph, or any other) which I can use to automate generation and deletion of the Client Secrets?
2. Is there a limit on how many Client Secrets there can be within a single app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there an API (Graph, or any other) which I can use to automate
> generation and deletion of the Client Credentials Secrets?

You can generate the client secret by calling [Add Password](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-addpassword?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) api, or delete the client secret by calling [remove Password](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-removepassword?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) api.

Please note that `{id}` in the api is the `Object ID`.

[image]

> Is there a limit on how many Client Secrets there can be within a
> single app?

It depends on whether your application supports personal account login. If your application supports personal account login, you can only create two client secrets at most.

If your application only supports work account login, there will be no limit to the number of client secrets created.

You can learn about or modify the account types supported by the application by viewing the **manifest** of the application.  It is the [signInAudience](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-app-manifest#signinaudience-attribute) attribute in the manifest.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below sample code for the generating the application credentials :

```
var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider );

var passwordCredential = new PasswordCredential
{
    DisplayName = "Password name"
};

await graphClient.Applications["{application-id}"]
    .AddPassword(passwordCredential)
    .Request()
    .PostAsync();
```

[API Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-addpassword?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#request)

Answer (score 0):

**- First answer**

```
TOKEN=$(curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
        -d "client_id=${CLIENT_ID}&client_secret=${CLIENT_SECRET}&grant_type=client_credentials&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F.default" \
        https://login.microsoftonline.com/${TENANT_ID}/oauth2/v2.0/token | \
        python3 -c "import sys, json; print(json.load(sys.stdin)['access_token'])")

OBJECT_ID=23cfbbde-xxxx-4af0-9f55-xxxxxxxxxxxx

curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer ${TOKEN}" -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
        --data '{"passwordCredential": {"displayName": "Enable only 2 years"}}' \
        https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/${OBJECT_ID}/addPassword
```

**- Second answer**

```
{"error":{"code":"TooManyAppPasswords","message":"Not allowed to add 3 passwords. You can only add a maximum of 2 passwords."}}
```